# Java stream - Performant way to update hierarchical object

Tags: java, java-stream, protobuf-java

I need to update an internal object matching criteria. This internal object is deep inside a large object with a hierarchy. The object is something like

```
ObjectA {
  List ObjectB {
    List Object C{ 
      int customerId;
      String customerStatus;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to update "customerStatus" only if customerId is matched to "123".

This entire objectA is stored in the database as a single object (in the real world, this is a protobuf object. Therefore this object is not updated in place)

The non-stream way involves a bunch of loops

```
List<ObjectB> objectBList = objectA.getObjectBList();
List<ObjectB> updatedObjectBList = new ArrayList<>();

for(objectB: objectBList) {
   List<ObjectC> objectCList = objectB.getObjectCList();
   
   List<ObjectC> updatedObjectCList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(objectC: objectCList) {
      if(objectC.getCustomerId() == 123) {
         objectC = createNewObjectCwithUpdatedStatus("UpdatedStatus");
      }

     updatedObjectCList.add(objectC);
   }

   updatedObjectBList.addObjectCList(updatedObjectCList);  
}

updatedObjectA.addObjectBList(updatedObjectBList);

writeUpdateObjectA_to_storage(updatedObjectA);
```

Is there a way to write this multiple IF condition using streams option?

Comment: Note that nothing is going to perform better than your loops, it's just that you *might* be able to write something that looks simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear from your code why you are adding the lists back to the objects once you do the update. As far as I can see you are updating the c objects in place (i.e. they are mutable) so it's not clear why they need to be re-added to the A and B objects.

Assuming that's a mistake, you could just flatten out the hierarchy and then do the updates:

```
getObjectBList().stream().flatMap(ObjectB::getObjectCList)
    .filter(c -> c.getCustomerId() == 123)
    .forEach(c -> c.setCustomerStatus("updated"));
```

If there's a reason to create a new list then that can be achieved as well but how to do it best depends on why you want to do that.

Comment: oh apologies, I just realized that my setCustomerStatus method was an in place update. An actual object is a protobuf object that can not be updated in place and needs a replacement with updated object that is a copy of the original one with new status. Just changed the example

Answer (score 0):

This is another option if you don't want to flat it

```
// Say you have objA reference

objA.getObjectBList().forEach(objBList -> objBList.getObjectCList().
stream().filter(objCList-> objCList.getCustomerId() == 123)
.forEach(c -> c.setCustomerStatus("updated"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If all objects are immutable, you can try following solution.

```java
    record C(int customerId, String customerStatus){}
    record B(List<C> getObjectCList){}
    record A(List<B> getObjectBList){}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        var objectA = new A(new ArrayList<>());
        var newObjectBList = objectA.getObjectBList().stream().map(objectB -> {
            var newObjectCList = objectB.getObjectCList().stream().map(objectC -> {
                return objectC.customerId == 123 ? new C(objectC.customerId, "UpdatedStatus") : objectC;
            }).toList();
            return new B(newObjectCList);
        }).toList();

        var newObjectA = new A(newObjectBList);
    }
```

Actually, this is a functional programming style.